# Django search in one to one field

Tags: python, django, search

Wanna do search field by multiple fields from different classes in models.
So I have model 1

```
class Man(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = models.DateField()
```

And model 2

```
class Data(models.Model):
    man = models.OneToOneField(
                                    Man,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    primary_key=True
                                    )
    data = models.JSONField(null=False)
```

And I'm trying to create search for field Man.name and then for some fields from JSON blob.
My views.py

```
class DataList(generics.ListAPIView):
    search_fields = ['man.name']
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, )
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

But when I'm trying to run it I have an error cause it can't access field man.name. So how can I acces it for searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access attributes from a related object you need to write using __ instead of ., so the correct version would be:

```
search_fields = ['man__name']
```

This is explained on documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/), you can search for the section that says "You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField with the lookup API double-underscore notation"